# Button outside list, update variables inside list

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

What I have is a list of documents that have different fields.
I have a button called Submit - when this is clicked it changes the value of my dropdown from "Not in progress" to "Submit".

My flow triggers and its all working fine - except they need to refresh the page to see this working.

When I added in a simple jquery location refresh it just keeps refreshing the page non stop.

I've removed the refresh out of the code, how can I achieve this without breaking the page again :)

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var targetListItem;
$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', execOperation);
});

function execOperation() {
    try {
        var  clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();      
        var myWeb = clientContext.get_web();
        var selectedItems  = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(clientContext);
        var myList = myWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('Quality');
        var itemArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {            
             myListItem = myList.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id);

            myListItem.set_item('Submit','Submit');
            myListItem.update();
            itemArray[i] = myListItem;
             clientContext.load(itemArray[i]);
             clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }   

            function onQuerySucceeded() {


location.reload();
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}


</script>

<input id="submitDocButton" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="execOperation();"></input>
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens due to reload function so please replace

```
location.reload();
```

With

```
window.location = window.location.href;
```

And it will work fine.

More details please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405117/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-href-and-window-location) stackoverflow link